# Calculating the mode using python

Tags: python-3.x, standards, mode, median, deviation

I am trying to write a simple little program that calculates the mean, median, mode and standard deviation of a given set of numbers, but I am having trouble writting the script for the mode part, any help? I am using python 3.3.2

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help you out when you get stuck, but we won't do all of the work for you. :)

Comment: do you want to see the entire script or that section in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Counter module:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter('extremely')
c
```

Out[4]: Counter({'e': 3, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1, 'x': 1})

```
c.items()
```

Out[7]: [('e', 3), ('m', 1), ('l', 1), ('r', 1), ('t', 1), ('y', 1), ('x', 1)]

```
srted = sorted(c.items(), key= lambda (k,v): -v)
srted
```

Out[9]: [('e', 3), ('m', 1), ('l', 1), ('r', 1), ('t', 1), ('y', 1), ('x', 1)]

```
top = srted[0]
top
```

Out[11]: ('e', 3)

```
k,v = top
k
```

Out[13]: 'e'

```
v
```

Out[14]: 3

Comment: i.e. pass counter some sequence\iterable, in this case I used the string "extremely" as an iterable of chars.